# Check activity of authors during period

Tags: views

I would like to have some sort of management system in the control panel where the management people can view the activity of the authors during a certain period.

So: A person with a certain role (management) must have a management tab in his administration menu where he can see the names of all authors + their amount of articles they have created during a certain period, where the manager can choose the start and enddate of this period.

Example:

Manager chooses:

1 september 2015 - 30 september 2015

and then he gets an overview of all authors and their amount of articles made that month.

Is there a module by any chance that already has this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to those who might wonder the same as me: apparently there is no module yet that does this, which surprises me, as it seemed such a basic request to me.

So you have to do it yourself.

For those who need it, I hereby give you my own solution, but ofcourse other possibilities are available.

I made this with a combination of views & total control module.

Total Control gives you a nice dashboard which you can fill with views. For the view itself, you just have to use the aggregate function and a relationship.

1. Relationship: 'Content: Author'
2. Use AJAX: Yes (this is to make sure filters can be exposed in blocks)
3. Use Aggregation: Yes
4. Make a table with following fields and filters:

   - Field: '(author) User: Name'
   - Field: 'Content: Nid' (Aggregation: Count (Distinct))
   - Filter: 'Content: Post date' => Exposed

extra fields are possible, like I have also added the date of the last article that person made in this specific period, which could also be handy for activity monitoring. To do this, use the field 'Content: Post date' and add the aggregation setting MAX to it.

Hope this helps others in case they are looking for something similar that is easy to maintain, without having to invent things that already exist.